# Concatenate spiders in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to concatenate mulitple spiders in Scrapy, so that the output of one feeds the other one. I am aware of the way Scrapy is used to concatenate parse functions and use the Meta parameter of the request to comunicate the item.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = [url1]
    def parse(self, response):
        # parse code and item generated
        yield scrapy.Request(url2, call_back=self.parse2, meta={'item': item})

    def parse2(self, response):
       item = response.meta['item']            
       # parse2 code
```

But I have a very long list of parsing functions to concatenate and this increasing complexity would be more modular and easier to debug with multiple spiders.

Thanks!

Comment: just setup some `cron` with the executions I think, about passing information from one spider to another I would be better to handle it on separate files, dbs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

approach other than the cronjob schedulibg would be to override `close_spider` signal

as you have written multiple spiders for each use-case

next you should override close_spider signal and call the next spider from there , using script.

you need do this signal override for all spiders and call up next dependent spider  as soon as current spiders completes it's operation